# How to save an aspose workbook (.xlsx) to aws s3 using java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, xlsx, aspose

I want to save Aspose worbook (.xlsx) to AWS S3 using java. Any help?

Providing S3 path directly to workbook.save("s3://...") will not work.

I am creating this file in AWS EMR Cluster. I can save this file in the same cluster and then move the file to S3. But I would like to know if there is any way of saving it directly to S3. I looked for answers but did not get any.

Comment: What have you tried, and what difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: Aspose.Cells for Java can save workbook (.xlsx) to streams or file path, but the file path should be accessible seamlessly and directly. Could you try to accomplish the task (save a file to aws s3)directly using java.io classes? If not, you cannot do the same via Aspose.Cells.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AmjadSahi I tried to save it directly to S3. It did not work. As a work around I saved it to EC2 instance and then moved the file to S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the file in EMR Cluster and then move it to S3, then delete the file from EMR Cluster. The code snippet is given below:

```
workbook.save("temp.xlsx");
File file = new File("temp.xlsx");
InputStream dataStream = new FileInputStream(file);
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .build();
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3Key, dataStream, metadata));          
file.delete();
```